# How to increase brightness with OpenCV.js?

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I *found a way* to do it, but it's very heavy and makes everything laggy (mainly because I'm re-creating the mat pixel by pixel).

```
for (let x = 0; x < src.cols; x++) {
for (let y = 0; y < src.rows; y++) {
  for (let c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
    if(c != 3){
      if((src.data[y * src.cols * src.channels() + x * src.channels() + c]+lum_val) < 255){
          dst.data[y * dst.cols * dst.channels() + x * dst.channels() + c] = (src.data[y * src.cols * src.channels() + x * src.channels() + c]+lum_val);
        }else{
          dst.data[y * dst.cols * dst.channels() + x * dst.channels() + c] = 255;
        }
      }else{
        dst.data[y * dst.cols * dst.channels() + x * dst.channels() + c] = (src.data[y * src.cols * src.channels() + x * src.channels() + c]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a **function** that does the same thing more efficiently ? Or maybe a **simpler way** which leads to the same result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow [OpenCV Tutorial: Changing the contrast and brightness of an image!](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html)

[convertScaleAbs(src, dst, alpha, beta)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d)

> Scales, calculates absolute values, and converts the result to 8-bit.
>
> On each element of the input array, the function convertScaleAbs
>   performs three operations sequentially: scaling, taking an absolute
>   value, conversion to an unsigned 8-bit type
>
> Parameters:
>
> src input array
>
> dst output array
>
> alpha   optional scale factor
>
> beta optional delta added to the scaled values

Comment: @Val_ there's a JS binding for convertScaleAbs. See https://github.com/ucisysarch/opencvjs/search?q=convertscaleabs&unscoped_q=convertscaleabs